# Converting an .EFX (eFax) File to PDF/JPG Without eFax Messenger?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, fax, efax

Yeah, that's right, somebody sent me a fax, possibly from the the '90s, but I won't know until I am able to open it.

eFax Messenger won't install on my 64-bit Windows version, and the site won't let me download in anything other than .EFX format. I've since changed the setting to use PDF in the accounts panel, but it won't let me download old faxes in PDF.

Other than installing eFax into a 32-bit Windows VM, what other solutions are there that work on 64-bit Windows?

Update: Looks like [downloading eFax 4.3 from CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Messenger-for-eFax/3000-2064_4-10601634.html) did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.vistax64.com/software/180497-problem-w-efax.html), eFax Messenger 4.3 (not the 4.4) works fine on Vista 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work quite right (script errors) under Windows 7 x64, but it works well enough to be functional and convert the document.